# A failsafe method of adding a picture to a USB drive background?

Tags: macos, usb, usb-storage

I'm struggling to get a background picture to 'stick' on a USB drive i'm setting up.

In OSX i open the USB drive, place the picture file on the drive, adjust my window size etc & set the View Options (cmd + J) to use the picture as background.

When i try the USB drive on another Mac the window is white and no visual setup information has been saved.

Any ideas ? I'm totally at a loss .

Answer (score 2):

Does the background image come back when you plug the drive into the original Mac? Where is the image stored? On the USB drive or your local hard disk?

Are you correctly unmounting the drive by dragging it to the Trash (which will turn into an eject symbol) before unplugging it? Not doing so can result in data not being correctly written to the drive.

Is the [Desktop Services Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) being saved correctly? This is a hidden file called `.DS_Store` that is saved in every directory and contains information about icon location and background images. To check, open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal, then type `ls -a [drag your disk on to the Terminal window]`. This should be created automatically, however there are utilities, such as [CleanMyMac](http://macpaw.com/uk/cleanmymac) that suppress or delete them on external drives and network shares - do you have one installed?

What file system is the drive using? To find out, select it in the Finder, then go File -> Get Info and look at the "Format" field. I'm not sure it'll work if the format is anything other than Mac OS Extended or Mac OS Extended (Journaled) (FAT32 is a common one for USB drives out of the box). It may help to re-format it as such using Disk Utility, although don't do so if you want to use it with a non-Macintosh computer.

Comment: Thanks for your response; unfortunately all of the above has been set on the USB & nothing changes... i get the USB drive looking exactly the way i want it to on 1 Mac, take it to another & bam, all my visual setup has gone. I tried restoring a dmg to the drive via Disk Utility with no success . The strange thing is another dmg i built years ago which i restored (w/ Disk Util) worked ok - all visuals fine... but i can't find any difference between this old dmg & my new dmg - both HFS, read-only, compressed... :[